# Status messages related to save/update actions

Tags: asp.net, .net, workflow-foundation, status

I'm in a .NET environment and when a user performs a save or update action, Foundation pops up a status message 'processing...' or 'saving...' or 'refreshing...', then 'saved.' After a given amount of time, the message will disappear,sometimes before the given action is really complete. How can I access this functionality and extend the time these status messages appear on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to implement ajax update panel, and add UpdateProgress control and associate AssociatedUpdatePanelID with Update Panel id. for ex:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelId">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="Refreshing"></asp:Label>
                </ProgressTemplate>
               </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

hope this help.